# Implementing a CMS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, content-management-system, c1-cms

I am using the CMS Composite c1 & run it in my local environment effectively using visual studio and composites UX. After putting the CMS on my web server What other components are needed to run a live site effectively? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

No other component are needed. Just put "as is" (dont run "publish" command)  your files in your website server and thats are all.